# ¿Como pasar un array a consulta SQL en un IN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, array, php7

Supongamos que tengo la tabla 'Sucursal', con los campos:
region_ID | sucursal_ID | nombre_Sucrusal

Y necesito hacer la consulta 
`sql="SELECT * FROM Sucursal WHERE region_ID IN (?)";`

¿Como hago para pasar un array al signo de interrogación? Dicho array puede variar en cantidad de elementos y sus valores. Tengo funcionando esta misma consulta en otras consultas, con la diferencia que le paso un valor por cada signo de interrogación en forma de Strings.

Estoy ocupando `PHP 7`, `SQLSRV`, `SQL Server 2012`

Mi consulta es

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($con_serv, $sql, $datosFormulario, array("Scrollable"=>'static'));
```

Comment: puedes enviarlo mediante un sp, el cual es un varcha o nvarchar sin embargo recuerda que al usar la clausula IN el valor máximo recomendable es de 8 elementos a comparar. Ej: select * from ejemplo where id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

Comment: Algo como esto @david-santos ?  
`$sql = "{call [dbo].[myStoredProcedure](?,?,?)}";`   
`$datosFormulario = array(array('02','03','09'));`  
 `$stmt = sqlsrv_query($con_serv, $sql, $datosFormulario, array("Scrollable"=>'static'));`

Comment: creo que no me explique bien. dentro el sp vas a ejecutar el sql que vas a generar. es decir al hacer un parametro de in y concatenar a tu sql a ejecutar.

Comment: La propuesta de David no sólo tiene sugerencias extrañas como decir que el máximo de elementos a comparar debería ser 8. También abre la puerta a inyección de SQL. Lo mejor sería que investigaras acerca de como enviar un parámetro tipo tabla o usar un splitter como el [DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muchas gracias @davidsantos  y @LuisCazares.

Con sus comentarios, resolví de dos formas. La primera fue crear una función que agregara los valores al IN antes de enviar la consulta. A modo de una inyección de código, y luego cree una función que retornara la tabla como mencionas @LuisCazares.

Al final me que de con esta función en SQL Server, al ver las posibilidades que tiene para futuras consultas. Dejo el código.

```
-- ========================================
-- Fecha de creación:   26/07/2019
-- Nombre:              splitstring
-- Descripción:         Separa un string, mediante un delimitador (char)
--                      y regresa los valores en forma de tabla
-- Parametros:          stringToSplit - texto a separar
--                      delimiter - caracter delimitador 
-- ========================================
-- Ejemplos: 
-- SELECT name  FROM dbo.splitstring(?, ',')

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[splitstring] ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX), @Delimiter char(1) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

Comment: Podrias explicar como usarias esto? por lo menos a mi no me quedo clara esta solucion. No es mas facil transformar el array en el origen a una lista separadas por comas y pasar un varchar como parametro desde el origen?

Comment: Justo intente eso desde el inicio, enviando los ID como int o varchar. No se si por usar el controlador SQLSRV, al momento de ver la traza no se colocaba de forma adecuada en la consulta (tomaba todo como un solo varchar).
Intente jugar con las comillas dobles, simples y con la diagonal invertida. Pero en ninguno de los casos funciono. 
Me quedaba claro que necesita una subconsulta, pero que fuera un poco más dinámica desde lo que evaluaba en PHP. 
*Por lo que comento @LuisCazares,  necesitaba arrojar una table en el IN.

Comment: Ahhh ahi entendi tu problema... a ver si encontramos el metodo "mas mejor" para hacer esto...

Comment: la función que hice en PHP me ayuda a modificar el sql, antes de enviar la consulta. Esto me es útil cuando requiero que el numero de columnas varia en el sql. Pero cuando necesito modificar los valores del lado del where me funciono el splitter

Comment: Esta bien. Esta es la forma correcta dada lo "vieja" de tu DB. En bases mas modernas, esta funcion ya viene incorporada en la DB (string_split)